# Load a new div into exiting div with load more button

Tags: javascript

I wanna like that some plugin just one thing must be different there is have 2 links for 2 div i wanna show there example 10 div but with only one button like "Load More" how i can do this ?

html

```
<a href="#hidden1" class="link">Click1</a>
<a href="#hidden2" class="link">Click2</a>
<div id="outer">
<div id="inner">Initial content</div>
</div> 
<div style="display:none" id="hidden1">After click event showing hidden 1</div>
<div style="display:none" id="hidden2">After click event showing hidden 2</div>
```

Js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.link').click(function() 
                     {
        var id = $(this).attr('href'); 
                         $('#inner').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $('#inner').html($(id).html());
            $('#inner').fadeIn('slow');


        })
    })
})
```

CSS

```
#hideMsg{
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G5qGs/2/

Comment: from single click you want all the 10 div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it something like this.

Create a load more button

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="loadmore">Load More</a>
```

Use javascript like below

```
 var count = 1;
    $('#loadmore').click(function() {
        $('#inner').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $('#inner').html($("#hidden" + count).html());
            $('#inner').fadeIn('slow');
            count++;
        })
    });
```

Working example

http://jsfiddle.net/G5qGs/25/

P.S : You might want to display "No more content" at the end. that can be achieved using a simple if else condition

Comment: I exactly want that !! Thank you so much!